# iOS and JSON nesting issue

Tags: objective-c, json

I am working on an app for a game server company and part of the app requires the user to see a list of his or her game servers and whether or not they are online, offline, how many players on them, the server name, etc. This data is all found in a JSON file hosted on the web updated from a MySQL database.

Using the code below, I can't seem to get it working. Now, please understand it is one of my first times working with JSON and have no choice as this is what the client requested. I talked to my partner but he couldn't seem to debug the issue himself.

The error I get is something like:

```
No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'objectForKey:'
```

I've tried several versions of the code, all with no success.

It would be much appreciated if you could please help me debug this code and get it working along with the commented out section near the bottom updating the TableViewCells with the server name, players online, and status (0=offline, 1=online, 2=busy, 3=suspended, -1=unable to start).

Please note that the format of the JSON file must remain as is and is only possible to make very minor changes.

Thank you,
Michael S.

**My header file:**

- http://pastebin.com/EkuwVSmY

**My main file:**

- http://pastebin.com/09Ju0uDu

**My JSON file:**

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "error": "",
    "debug": "2 server(s)",
    "result": {
        "servers": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "Test",
                "players": 0,
                "slots": 10,
                "status": 3
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "title": "Creative Spawn",
                "players": 0,
                "slots": 5,
                "status": -1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The block that gives me the error is:

```
NSArray *serverResults = [[news objectForKey:@"result"] objectForKey:@"servers"];

if ([[[serverResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"status"] isEqual:@"1"]) {
    serverPlayers.text = @"10000000";
}
```

Comment: Could you post the block that gives you the error?

Comment: The code for assigning `serverResults` you posted is different than the whats on pastebin. Which one are you actually using?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, @MikeD, I am using the one I posted here.

Comment: Go to json.org and study the syntax for the 5-10 minutes it takes to learn it.  Your problem is that you're trying to treat an array like an dictionary/"object" -- JSON is a mix of the two.  If you learn to read the syntax you can easily see which is which.

Comment: And don't do this: `if ([[[serverResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"status"] isEqual:@"1"])`. Instead, break it into an assignment to "serverItem" to receive the result of objectAtIndes, an assignment to "status" (starting with "serverItem" to receive the objectForKey result, and an then the if isEqual.  This makes things MUCH easier to understand and MUCH easier to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you get points out that you are working on an NSArray instead of a NSDictionary. There is no method `objectForKey` defined on an NSArray. So what you could do is to debug your Webservice response and check the Data types.

Regarding at your output from JSON it should be like that:

*NSDictionary* (Keys: status, error, debug, result, servers)
servers is an *NSArray* which has *NSDictionaries* as elements.

To get the title of a server:

```
NSDictionary *resultDict = [news objectForKey:@"result"];
NSArray *servers = [resultDict objectForKey:@"servers"];
NSDictionary *firstServer = [servers objectAtIndex:0]; // I fetch here the first server
NSString *titleOfFirstServer = [firstServer objectForKey:@"title"];
NSNumber *statusOfFirstServer = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[firstServer objectForKey:@"status"] intValue];
```

To iterate over all servers you should do it like that:

```
 NSDictionary *resultDict = [news objectForKey:@"result"];
 NSArray *servers = [resultDict objectForKey:@"servers"];

 for(NSDictionary *server in servers) {
   NSString *title = [server objectForKey:@"title"];
   NSNumber *status = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[server objectForKey:@"status"] intValue];

   NSLog(@"%@%d", title, [status intValue]);
 }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, except I am getting another error now, "use of undeclared identifier 'jsonResponse'"

Comment: Yeah, I didnt know what the variable name was. It should be "news" instead of jsonResponse.

Comment: Now I get this error after changing jsonResponse to news: No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'objectForKey:' Error's title is : ARC Semantic Issue.

Comment: What is news exactly? Can you please check with the debugger if its an NSArray or an NSDictionary.

Comment: 'news' is an NSArray as defined in the header file, I could change it if needed but this was the only way I found to get JSON file from the web, I used a tutorial.

Comment: Change it to NSDictionary. Then I guess it should work. If this JSON code is all you get from the server than its a NSDictionary instead of a NSArray :)

Comment: That fixed the error, but do I have to create variables like titleOfFirstServer and statusOfFirstServer for EACH server? I don't control how many the client has, he could have 1 or 100

Comment: No you don't. This was just an example to show you, how you can access the values of the Dictionaries. Please do not forget to mark this question as answered, if its solved now..

Comment: using that code I only get the first server, and it shows it 4 times (http://puu.sh/3QhOT.png) when in the JSON there are 2 completely seperate servers.

{"status":"OK","error":"","debug":"2 server(s)","result":{"servers":[{"id":1,"title":"Test","players":0,"slots":10,"status":3},{"id":2,"title":"Creative Spawn","players":0,"slots":5,"status":-1}]}}

Comment: Yeah this is because in the example code I'm only fetching the data from the first server  (objectAtIndex:0 with objectAtIndex:1 you could get the second one). But anyway if you want to get all servers you have to iterate over the NSArray.. But this is really basic stuff. You should first do some tutorials on Arrays, Dictionaries and so on..

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply, but is there any reason it shows it 4 times like in the provided screenshot? And changing it to this gives me a SIGABRT: http://pastebin.com/jTVAWCK0

Comment: I'll have to check into that, now to fix the SIGABRT! :/

Comment: Would it be possible for you to help me with setting up some sort of 'loop' or something to allow multiple servers to be listed and not just the 0th or 1st entry in JSON? ' NSDictionary *myServer = [servers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; ' seems to give me SIGABRT every time.